# Using API JSON data in react conditional return

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I have a small (never for production) Express/React app, I'm validating a hashed pin in express and returning either `message: false` if validation fails or `message: <cardnumber>` if validation is succefull. In my react frontend I want to eventually redirect if it returns a cardnumber, but first I'm just trying to conditionally render a component.

I have a constructor for the json response

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      cardnumber: '',
      pin: '',
      servercardnumber: {
        message: ''
      }
    };
```

Then I'm getting the data from API like this

```
  const url = '/api/login';
    const serverResponse = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    });
    const json = await serverResponse.json();
    console.log(json);

    this.setState(
      prevState => {
        return {
          servercardnumber: json.cardnumber
        };
      },
      () => {
        console.log(this.state.cardnumber);
      }
    );
  };
```

Then I'm trying to conditionally render a material ui component in my react return

```
 render() {
    const { cardnumber, pin, servercardnumber } = this.state;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Card>{!servercardnumber ? <Card> Server says no</Card> : null}</Card>
        {console.log('server says:')}
        {console.log(servercardnumber)}
```

The `{console.log(servercardnumber)}` first returns the correct servercardnumber, then returns undefined.

What I need is to see the response in my conditional render, and show the rendered component if login is succefull (or show if not succefull, as long as I get it to conditionally render)

I've done a bunch of changes to this code in my attempt to get this to work, so it may seem a bit cluttered.

Full front end code for the relevant file: https://pastebin.com/VbdzmE4E
Server code for the relevant file: https://pastebin.com/TZ35NZxa

Comment: Shouldn't you be setting the `servercardnumber` state to `json.message` instead of `json.cardumber`?

Comment: You are correct Tyler, thank you so much! I've spent so much time on this, should have just re-read the whole code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reposting my comment here so that it the question can be resolved.

The state property `servercardnumber` should be set to `json.message` instead of `json.cardnumber`.